# Assertion failure from Cocos2d CCNode.m on iOS device. Fine in simulator. Why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Can anyone shed any light on the reason for the following failure:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[Alien rotation], 
/Users/admininstrator/Documents/moonweed/Star Pilot v4.0/Star Pilot 
#1/Libraries/cocos2d/CCNode.m:258

2014-11-06 23:28:51.680 Star Pilot #1[2141:987748] *** Terminating app due to uncaught 
exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'CCNode#rotation. rotationalSkewX 
!= rotationalSkewY. Don't know which one to return'
```

Looking at the Cocos2d source, I can see that the Assertion is coming from CCNode.m, from the method below:

```
-(float) rotation
{
    CCPhysicsBody *body = GetBodyIfRunning(self);
    if(body){
        return -CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(body.absoluteRadians) + 
NodeToPhysicsRotation(self.parent);
    } else {
        NSAssert( _rotationalSkewX == _rotationalSkewY, @"CCNode#rotation. rotationalSkewX != rotationalSkewY. Don't know which one to return");
        return _rotationalSkewX;
    }
}
```

The code runs fine on all simulators, using Xcode 6.1. But on my iPhone 5, it crashes. I'm struggling to figure why? I'm currently using Cocos2d V3.x.

Comment: When you get an error like this, it may be possible that the resource that is in question did not get copied to the iOS device. Have you tested deleting the app off of the iOS device, doing a clean, the testing again on the device?

Comment: Yes. Cleaned the project, removed the App, re-built and run again. It's also quite difficult to reproduce. What I mean is, it does happen each time my GameScene.m runs. But it does it at different intervals. Runs great on the simulator. No issues what-so-ever. I'm wondering if I need to get a later version of Cocos2d. I'm running the version that has the auto-installer built in, so version: 3.1.0. I Can see that version 3.2.1 is out. Anyone have any ideas that it might be to to do with that? i guess it's worth a shot eh?

Comment: For anyone that would like a shot at this, I've also started a thread on http://forum.cocos2d-swift.org/t/assertion-failure-from-cocos2d-ccnode-m-on-ios-device-fine-in-simulator-why/15756/2